# ASP.NET Response.Redirect, remove metasapiens page methods

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-4.5

I am looking to replace Metasapiens PageMethods, essentially this creates a class that allows for runtime checking of the link,

e.g.

```
Response.Redirect(MyPageMethods.Web.Display.Customer(custId));
```

This would go the the display page, and then call the customer method with the customer id.  However I want to update to .Net 4.5 and the development of PageMethods stopped in 2007.
(http://metasapiens.com/pagemethods/)

Therefore is there any best practices / easy ways of making my pages redirect to links which can be compiler checked as such when the project is built?

Comment: Theres the new Friendly URL, that can help you to build this as well. http://www.hanselman.com/blog/IntroducingASPNETFriendlyUrlsCleanerURLsEasierRoutingAndMobileViewsForASPNETWebForms.aspx

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In case anyone ever finds this, I made it so that I created a quick application that ran through the xml file the program generated, and created classes that had a url and all the methods within it for example:

```cs
namespace PS.Web.Pages.Maintenance.Area.Display
{
    public static class DisplayArea
    {
        public static string URL = "/Pages/Maintenance/Area/Display/DisplayArea.aspx";

        public static string Show(System.Int32 areaId)
        {
            return string.Format("{0}?PageMethod=Show&areaId={1}", URL, areaId);
        }
    }
}
```

Then you just need to add something into a base page so that on page load we can initiliase the page, and pass in the parameters

```cs
protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e) 
{
    InitiatePage();
}

private void InitiatePage()
{
    var queryString = Request.QueryString;

    var pageMethodObject = queryString["PageMethod"];
    if (pageMethodObject != null)
    {
        string methodName = pageMethodObject.ToString();

        Type ty = this.GetType().BaseType;

        MethodInfo methodInfo = ty.GetMethod(methodName, BindingFlags.NonPublic | BindingFlags.Instance | BindingFlags.Public);

        if (methodInfo != null)
        {
            ParameterInfo[] parameters = methodInfo.GetParameters();

            if (parameters.Length == 0)
            {
                methodInfo.Invoke(this, null);
            }
            else
            {
                IList<object> parametersArray = new List<object>();

                foreach (var parameter in parameters)
                {
                    var value = queryString[parameter.Name];
                    object obj = null;
                    if (parameter.ParameterType.IsEnum)
                    {
                        obj = Enum.Parse(parameter.ParameterType, value);
                    }
                    else
                    {
                        obj = Convert.ChangeType(value, parameter.ParameterType);
                    }
                    parametersArray.Add(obj);
                }

                //try and run the method
                methodInfo.Invoke(this, parametersArray.ToArray());
            }
        }
    }
}
```

now it should automatically all link up....  So now the metasapiens page methods are gone and we don't have to worry about them!  - Obviously when we create out classes with the URL buried in the parameters MUST match the parameters of the methods we are calling into else this will not work!